# Why does Ruby create a new object for "var = var + 1" but not "var = var + 0"?

Tags: ruby, object

I have this Ruby code:

```
var1 = 10
puts var1.object_id
var1 = var1 + 0
puts var1.object_id
var1 = var1 + 1
puts var1.object_id
```

The output is:

```
1> 21
2> 21
3> 23
```

Question: why does Ruby create a new object when adding a non-zero value but not when adding 0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Internally Ruby¹ does not create objects at all when working with Fixnums. Instead the implementation uses "tagged" pointers, that is if the least significant bit of a pointer is set, Ruby understand that this pointer does not actually point to an object, but rather encodes the value of a Fixnum directly. Therefore a Fixnum with the same numeric value will always be represented by the same pointer value.

¹ By which I mean the official Ruby interpreter - other implementations may handle this differently.

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby, `Fixnum`s, `true,` `false`, `nil` and `Symbol`s have predefined `object_id`s.

```
1.object_id #=> 3
2.object_id #=> 5
```

Adding `0` to a small integer doesn't change its value, and hence its `object_id` remains the same.

However if you run the same arithmetic on `Bignum`s, you'll get different `object_id`s.

```
a = 1073741824
puts a.object_id # => 7658076
b = a + 0
puts b # => 1073741824
puts b.object_id # => 7287012
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't. `10` and `11` are Fixnums. Sine there is only one Fixnum instance per Integer value, `10` has an object_id and `11` has an object_id. That's what you're seeing.

Comment: Being constant does not necessarily imply that the same value always has the same `object_id`. Floats and Bignums are constant, too, and they don't behave like that. Speaking of Bignums: This behavior applies to Fixnums, not all Integers.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has predifined objects

```
irb(main):001:0> 10.object_id
=> 21
irb(main):002:0> 11.object_id
=> 23
```

It's some natural numbers and even more

```
irb(main):003:0> true.object_id
=> 2
irb(main):004:0> false.object_id
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> nil.object_id
=> 4
irb(main):006:0> 0.object_id
=> 1
irb(main):007:0> -2.object_id
=> -3
```

and these ids doesn't change